# Why doesn't this variable display on page in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Trying to show the `@total` variable but it always says `0`.

What's the correct way to get it to display on the page?

Currently i am doing...

main.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do

  @array = [1, 7, 3, 0]
  @index = params[:index].to_i
  @total = 1

  def get_products_of_all_ints_except_at_index()
    @array.delete_at(@index)
    @array.each do |i|
      @total *= i
    end
  end
  get_products_of_all_ints_except_at_index()
erb :home
end
```

home.erb

```
<form action="/">

  <input type="number" name="index" placeholder="index">

  <button>Calculate</button>

</form>

<%= @total %>
```

Comment: apart from the answer, the best advise I can give you: do 'require "sinatra/reloader"' at teh beginning of your main file, in that way you can freely try and change while you don't have to restart the server every time

Comment: @peter hey, thanks. that's going to be really useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `@array`, the last element is `0`. Because you are iterating over it and multiplying the total with each element, total is `0` too.

Comment: Ugh, silly me. I put that 0 there earlier when i was trying to break the function. thank you!